# DAX: How to construct a "piecewise" measure?

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

I have a time series that looks very different before and after a certain date.

I have one measure that calculates the average value of the time series BEFORE that date, and another measure for the average value AFTER that date.

How do I melge them into 1 measure so that when I make a line chart in my front end tool, I see the one average before, and the other average after?

Comment: use a calculated column instead of a measure, throw both of you measures' logic in an If statement that is dependent on that special date.. i.e. if date is foo then do the first measure, if date is bar then do the other measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! Trick was using HASONEVALUE and VALUES in tandem to get "data type" agreement. The "combined" measure now displays the piecewise average I was after.

```
EventCount:= DISTINCTCOUNT([Event_Id])

Avg Daily Event Count Pre:= calculate([EventCount] / DISTINCTCOUNT([EventDate]), Event[EventDate] <= date(2018, 3, 1))

Avg Daily Event Count Post:= calculate([EventCount] / DISTINCTCOUNT([EventDate]), Event[EventDate] >= date(2018, 4, 1))

Avg Daily Event Count Combined:= if (
                HASONEVALUE(Event[EventDate]),
                    if(
                        values(Event[EventDate]) <= date(2018, 3, 1),
                            [Avg Daily Event Count Pre],
                            if(
                                values(Event[EventDate]) >= date(2018, 4, 1),
                                    [Avg Daily Event Count Post],
                                    blank()
                            )
                    )
                )
```